# Unable to form JSON string object from the values of textfields in add/remove textfields

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

I have done a add/remove textfields using jquery. I'm not able to form a JSON string from the values of the textfield in the interface on form submit.
Below is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/28h0L6eb/15/).
I want to form JSON string on form submit.
JSON to be of the format :

```
{"dataList":["Thanks for calling us","Please select from the following list"]}
```

How can I do it

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle has several problems

You have no form element, so your code: `$("form").submit(` does nothing as there is no form element to select

The other problem is you have no element with an id of `#welcome_notes` so your code:

```
$( '#welcome_notes input[id^=Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes]' ).serializeArray()
```

Amounts to nothing as there is no element `#welcome_notes` to select inputs from and serialize

The last problem is the element you have with id `Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes` is a div element not an input element so doing:

```
$("#Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes").val(json);
```

Has no effect because its not an input element and does not have a value. So create an input (type=hidden if you want it hidden) and give it a unique id and then use that to set the json value to.

[JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/28h0L6eb/16/)